# AWS SageMaker extimator.fit() failure: ValueError: SHA could not be resolved, git returned: b''"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, yolov5

I'm trying to train a YOLOv5 model on sagemaker and then deploy the trained model to an endpoint. I'm following this example:

[amazon-sagemaker-train-and-deploy-yolov5/notebooks/2 - Train and deploy with Amazon SageMaker](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-sagemaker-train-and-deploy-yolov5/blob/main/notebooks/2%20-%20Train%20and%20deploy%20with%20Amazon%20SageMaker/Custom-YOLOv5-Train-and-Deploy-on-Amazon-SageMaker.ipynb)

When I get to this line:

```
estimator.fit(train_input, job_name=job_name)
```

training fails with the following traceback:

```
Using provided s3_resource
INFO:sagemaker.image_uris:image_uri is not presented, retrieving image_uri based on instance_type, framework etc.
INFO:sagemaker:Creating training-job with name: yolov5-t-3705a49b-162a-4bc4-9a4e-b7d271ebbcc7
2024-01-04 16:36:26 Starting - Starting the training job...
2024-01-04 16:36:42 Starting - Preparing the instances for training......
2024-01-04 16:37:43 Downloading - Downloading input data...
2024-01-04 16:38:23 Downloading - Downloading the training image...........................
2024-01-04 16:42:30 Training - Training image download completed. Training in progress..bash: cannot set terminal process group (-1): Inappropriate ioctl for device
bash: no job control in this shell
2024-01-04 11:42:54,712 sagemaker-training-toolkit INFO     Imported framework sagemaker_pytorch_container.training
2024-01-04 11:42:54,738 sagemaker-training-toolkit INFO     No Neurons detected (normal if no neurons installed)
2024-01-04 11:42:54,751 sagemaker_pytorch_container.training INFO     Block until all host DNS lookups succeed.
2024-01-04 11:42:54,753 sagemaker_pytorch_container.training INFO     Invoking user training script.
2024-01-04 11:44:51,808 sagemaker-training-toolkit INFO     Installing dependencies from requirements.txt:
/opt/conda/bin/python3.8 -m pip install -r requirements.txt
Collecting gitpython>=3.1.30
Downloading GitPython-3.1.40-py3-none-any.whl (190 kB)
━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 190.6/190.6 kB 5.2 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib>=3.3 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 6)) (3.7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.22.2 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 7)) (1.22.2)
Requirement already satisfied: opencv-python>=4.1.1 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 8)) (4.7.0.68)
Collecting Pillow>=10.0.1
Downloading pillow-10.2.0-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_28_x86_64.whl (4.5 MB)
━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 4.5/4.5 MB 57.8 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Requirement already satisfied: psutil in /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 10)) (5.9.4)
Requirement already satisfied: PyYAML>=5.3.1 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 11)) (5.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: requests>=2.23.0 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 12)) (2.28.2)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=1.4.1 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 13)) (1.10.0)
Collecting thop>=0.1.1
Downloading thop-0.1.1.post2209072238-py3-none-any.whl (15 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: torch>=1.8.0 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 15)) (1.11.0+cu113)
Requirement already satisfied: torchvision>=0.9.0 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 16)) (0.12.0+cu113)
Requirement already satisfied: tqdm>=4.64.0 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 17)) (4.64.1)
Collecting ultralytics>=8.0.147
Downloading ultralytics-8.0.234-py3-none-any.whl (664 kB)
━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 664.3/664.3 kB 73.3 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Requirement already satisfied: pandas>=1.1.4 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 27)) (1.5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: seaborn>=0.11.0 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 28)) (0.12.2)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=65.5.1 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 42)) (65.6.3)
Collecting gitdb<5,>=4.0.1
Downloading gitdb-4.0.11-py3-none-any.whl (62 kB)
━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 62.7/62.7 kB 14.5 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Requirement already satisfied: packaging>=20.0 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from matplotlib>=3.3->-r requirements.txt (line 6)) (23.0)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.7 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from matplotlib>=3.3->-r requirements.txt (line 6)) (2.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: contourpy>=1.0.1 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from matplotlib>=3.3->-r requirements.txt (line 6)) (1.0.7)
Requirement already satisfied: importlib-resources>=3.2.0 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from matplotlib>=3.3->-r requirements.txt (line 6)) (5.10.2)
Requirement already satisfied: kiwisolver>=1.0.1 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from matplotlib>=3.3->-r requirements.txt (line 6)) (1.4.4)
Requirement already satisfied: cycler>=0.10 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from matplotlib>=3.3->-r requirements.txt (line 6)) (0.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied: fonttools>=4.22.0 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from matplotlib>=3.3->-r requirements.txt (line 6)) (4.38.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing>=2.3.1 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from matplotlib>=3.3->-r requirements.txt (line 6)) (3.0.9)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from requests>=2.23.0->-r requirements.txt (line 12)) (3.4)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from requests>=2.23.0->-r requirements.txt (line 12)) (1.26.14)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from requests>=2.23.0->-r requirements.txt (line 12)) (2022.12.7)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer<4,>=2 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from requests>=2.23.0->-r requirements.txt (line 12)) (2.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions in /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from torch>=1.8.0->-r requirements.txt (line 15)) (4.4.0)
Collecting py-cpuinfo
Downloading py_cpuinfo-9.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (22 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2020.1 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from pandas>=1.1.4->-r requirements.txt (line 27)) (2022.7.1)
Collecting smmap<6,>=3.0.1
Downloading smmap-5.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (24 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: zipp>=3.1.0 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from importlib-resources>=3.2.0->matplotlib>=3.3->-r requirements.txt (line 6)) (3.13.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.7->matplotlib>=3.3->-r requirements.txt (line 6)) (1.16.0)
Installing collected packages: py-cpuinfo, smmap, Pillow, thop, gitdb, gitpython, ultralytics
Attempting uninstall: Pillow
Found existing installation: Pillow 9.4.0
Uninstalling Pillow-9.4.0:
Successfully uninstalled Pillow-9.4.0
Successfully installed Pillow-10.2.0 gitdb-4.0.11 gitpython-3.1.40 py-cpuinfo-9.0.0 smmap-5.0.1 thop-0.1.1.post2209072238 ultralytics-8.0.234
WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package manager. It is recommended to use a virtual environment instead: https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv
[notice] A new release of pip is available: 23.0 -> 23.3.2
[notice] To update, run: pip install --upgrade pip
2024-01-04 11:44:55,402 sagemaker-training-toolkit INFO     Waiting for the process to finish and give a return code.
2024-01-04 11:44:55,403 sagemaker-training-toolkit INFO     Done waiting for a return code. Received 0 from exiting process.
2024-01-04 11:44:55,456 sagemaker-training-toolkit INFO     No Neurons detected (normal if no neurons installed)
2024-01-04 11:44:55,500 sagemaker-training-toolkit INFO     No Neurons detected (normal if no neurons installed)
2024-01-04 11:44:55,543 sagemaker-training-toolkit INFO     No Neurons detected (normal if no neurons installed)
2024-01-04 11:44:55,558 sagemaker-training-toolkit INFO     Invoking user script
Training Env:
{
    "additional_framework_parameters": {},
    "channel_input_dirs": {
        "training": "/opt/ml/input/data/training"
    },
    "current_host": "algo-1",
    "current_instance_group": "homogeneousCluster",
    "current_instance_group_hosts": [
        "algo-1"
    ],
    "current_instance_type": "ml.g4dn.2xlarge",
    "distribution_hosts": [],
    "distribution_instance_groups": [],
    "framework_module": "sagemaker_pytorch_container.training:main",
    "hosts": [
        "algo-1"
    ],
    "hyperparameters": {
        "batch-size": "8",
        "data": "custom-model.yaml",
        "device": "0",
        "epochs": 10,
        "project": "/opt/ml/model",
        "weights": "yolov5s.pt",
        "workers": "8"
    },
    "input_config_dir": "/opt/ml/input/config",
    "input_data_config": {
        "training": {
            "TrainingInputMode": "File",
            "S3DistributionType": "FullyReplicated",
            "RecordWrapperType": "None"
        }
    },
    "input_dir": "/opt/ml/input",
    "instance_groups": [
        "homogeneousCluster"
    ],
    "instance_groups_dict": {
        "homogeneousCluster": {
            "instance_group_name": "homogeneousCluster",
            "instance_type": "ml.g4dn.2xlarge",
            "hosts": [
                "algo-1"
            ]
        }
    },
    "is_hetero": false,
    "is_master": true,
    "is_modelparallel_enabled": null,
    "is_smddpmprun_installed": false,
    "job_name": "yolov5-t-3705a49b-162a-4bc4-9a4e-b7d271ebbcc7",
    "log_level": 20,
    "master_hostname": "algo-1",
    "model_dir": "/opt/ml/model",
    "module_dir": "s3://sagemaker-us-east-2-210862505627/yolov5-t-3705a49b-162a-4bc4-9a4e-b7d271ebbcc7/source/sourcedir.tar.gz",
    "module_name": "train",
    "network_interface_name": "eth0",
    "num_cpus": 8,
    "num_gpus": 1,
    "num_neurons": 0,
    "output_data_dir": "/opt/ml/output/data",
    "output_dir": "/opt/ml/output",
    "output_intermediate_dir": "/opt/ml/output/intermediate",
    "resource_config": {
        "current_host": "algo-1",
        "current_instance_type": "ml.g4dn.2xlarge",
        "current_group_name": "homogeneousCluster",
        "hosts": [
            "algo-1"
        ],
        "instance_groups": [
            {
                "instance_group_name": "homogeneousCluster",
                "instance_type": "ml.g4dn.2xlarge",
                "hosts": [
                    "algo-1"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "network_interface_name": "eth0"
    },
    "user_entry_point": "train.py"
}
Environment variables:
SM_HOSTS=["algo-1"]
SM_NETWORK_INTERFACE_NAME=eth0
SM_HPS={"batch-size":"8","data":"custom-model.yaml","device":"0","epochs":10,"project":"/opt/ml/model","weights":"yolov5s.pt","workers":"8"}
SM_USER_ENTRY_POINT=train.py
SM_FRAMEWORK_PARAMS={}
SM_RESOURCE_CONFIG={"current_group_name":"homogeneousCluster","current_host":"algo-1","current_instance_type":"ml.g4dn.2xlarge","hosts":["algo-1"],"instance_groups":[{"hosts":["algo-1"],"instance_group_name":"homogeneousCluster","instance_type":"ml.g4dn.2xlarge"}],"network_interface_name":"eth0"}
SM_INPUT_DATA_CONFIG={"training":{"RecordWrapperType":"None","S3DistributionType":"FullyReplicated","TrainingInputMode":"File"}}
SM_OUTPUT_DATA_DIR=/opt/ml/output/data
SM_CHANNELS=["training"]
SM_CURRENT_HOST=algo-1
SM_CURRENT_INSTANCE_TYPE=ml.g4dn.2xlarge
SM_CURRENT_INSTANCE_GROUP=homogeneousCluster
SM_CURRENT_INSTANCE_GROUP_HOSTS=["algo-1"]
SM_INSTANCE_GROUPS=["homogeneousCluster"]
SM_INSTANCE_GROUPS_DICT={"homogeneousCluster":{"hosts":["algo-1"],"instance_group_name":"homogeneousCluster","instance_type":"ml.g4dn.2xlarge"}}
SM_DISTRIBUTION_INSTANCE_GROUPS=[]
SM_IS_HETERO=false
SM_MODULE_NAME=train
SM_LOG_LEVEL=20
SM_FRAMEWORK_MODULE=sagemaker_pytorch_container.training:main
SM_INPUT_DIR=/opt/ml/input
SM_INPUT_CONFIG_DIR=/opt/ml/input/config
SM_OUTPUT_DIR=/opt/ml/output
SM_NUM_CPUS=8
SM_NUM_GPUS=1
SM_NUM_NEURONS=0
SM_MODEL_DIR=/opt/ml/model
SM_MODULE_DIR=s3://sagemaker-us-east-2-210862505627/yolov5-t-3705a49b-162a-4bc4-9a4e-b7d271ebbcc7/source/sourcedir.tar.gz
SM_TRAINING_ENV={"additional_framework_parameters":{},"channel_input_dirs":{"training":"/opt/ml/input/data/training"},"current_host":"algo-1","current_instance_group":"homogeneousCluster","current_instance_group_hosts":["algo-1"],"current_instance_type":"ml.g4dn.2xlarge","distribution_hosts":[],"distribution_instance_groups":[],"framework_module":"sagemaker_pytorch_container.training:main","hosts":["algo-1"],"hyperparameters":{"batch-size":"8","data":"custom-model.yaml","device":"0","epochs":10,"project":"/opt/ml/model","weights":"yolov5s.pt","workers":"8"},"input_config_dir":"/opt/ml/input/config","input_data_config":{"training":{"RecordWrapperType":"None","S3DistributionType":"FullyReplicated","TrainingInputMode":"File"}},"input_dir":"/opt/ml/input","instance_groups":["homogeneousCluster"],"instance_groups_dict":{"homogeneousCluster":{"hosts":["algo-1"],"instance_group_name":"homogeneousCluster","instance_type":"ml.g4dn.2xlarge"}},"is_hetero":false,"is_master":true,"is_modelparallel_enabled":null,"is_smddpmprun_installed":false,"job_name":"yolov5-t-3705a49b-162a-4bc4-9a4e-b7d271ebbcc7","log_level":20,"master_hostname":"algo-1","model_dir":"/opt/ml/model","module_dir":"s3://sagemaker-us-east-2-210862505627/yolov5-t-3705a49b-162a-4bc4-9a4e-b7d271ebbcc7/source/sourcedir.tar.gz","module_name":"train","network_interface_name":"eth0","num_cpus":8,"num_gpus":1,"num_neurons":0,"output_data_dir":"/opt/ml/output/data","output_dir":"/opt/ml/output","output_intermediate_dir":"/opt/ml/output/intermediate","resource_config":{"current_group_name":"homogeneousCluster","current_host":"algo-1","current_instance_type":"ml.g4dn.2xlarge","hosts":["algo-1"],"instance_groups":[{"hosts":["algo-1"],"instance_group_name":"homogeneousCluster","instance_type":"ml.g4dn.2xlarge"}],"network_interface_name":"eth0"},"user_entry_point":"train.py"}
SM_USER_ARGS=["--batch-size","8","--data","custom-model.yaml","--device","0","--epochs","10","--project","/opt/ml/model","--weights","yolov5s.pt","--workers","8"]
SM_OUTPUT_INTERMEDIATE_DIR=/opt/ml/output/intermediate
SM_CHANNEL_TRAINING=/opt/ml/input/data/training
SM_HP_BATCH-SIZE=8
SM_HP_DATA=custom-model.yaml
SM_HP_DEVICE=0
SM_HP_EPOCHS=10
SM_HP_PROJECT=/opt/ml/model
SM_HP_WEIGHTS=yolov5s.pt
SM_HP_WORKERS=8
PYTHONPATH=/opt/ml/code:/opt/conda/bin:/opt/conda/lib/python38.zip:/opt/conda/lib/python3.8:/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload:/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages:/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/smdebug-1.0.26b20230214-py3.8.egg:/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyinstrument-3.4.2-py3.8.egg:/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyinstrument_cext-0.2.4-py3.8-linux-x86_64.egg
Invoking script with the following command:
/opt/conda/bin/python3.8 train.py --batch-size 8 --data custom-model.yaml --device 0 --epochs 10 --project /opt/ml/model --weights yolov5s.pt --workers 8
2024-01-04 11:44:56,637 sagemaker-training-toolkit INFO     Exceptions not imported for SageMaker TF as Tensorflow is not installed.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 72, in <module>
GIT_INFO = check_git_info()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/contextlib.py", line 75, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwds)
  File "/opt/ml/code/utils/general.py", line 374, in check_git_info
commit = repo.head.commit.hexsha  # i.e. '3134699c73af83aac2a481435550b968d5792c0d'
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/git/refs/symbolic.py", line 274, in _get_commit
obj = self._get_object()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/git/refs/symbolic.py", line 267, in _get_object
return Object.new_from_sha(self.repo, hex_to_bin(self.dereference_recursive(self.repo, self.path)))
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/git/objects/base.py", line 94, in new_from_sha
oinfo = repo.odb.info(sha1)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/git/db.py", line 40, in info
    hexsha, typename, size = self._git.get_object_header(bin_to_hex(binsha))
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/git/cmd.py", line 1384, in get_object_header
return self.__get_object_header(cmd, ref)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/git/cmd.py", line 1371, in __get_object_header
return self._parse_object_header(cmd.stdout.readline())
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/git/cmd.py", line 1330, in _parse_object_header
raise ValueError("SHA could not be resolved, git returned: %r" % (header_line.strip()))
ValueError: SHA could not be resolved, git returned: b''
2024-01-04 11:45:00,757 sagemaker-training-toolkit INFO     Waiting for the process to finish and give a return code.
2024-01-04 11:45:00,757 sagemaker-training-toolkit INFO     Done waiting for a return code. Received 1 from exiting process.
2024-01-04 11:45:00,757 sagemaker-training-toolkit ERROR    Reporting training FAILURE
2024-01-04 11:45:00,757 sagemaker-training-toolkit ERROR    ExecuteUserScriptError:
ExitCode 1
ErrorMessage "raise ValueError("SHA could not be resolved, git returned: %r" % (header_line.strip()))
 ValueError: SHA could not be resolved, git returned: b''"
Command "/opt/conda/bin/python3.8 train.py --batch-size 8 --data custom-model.yaml --device 0 --epochs 10 --project /opt/ml/model --weights yolov5s.pt --workers 8"
2024-01-04 11:45:00,758 sagemaker-training-toolkit ERROR    Encountered exit_code 1

2024-01-04 16:45:32 Uploading - Uploading generated training model
2024-01-04 16:45:32 Failed - Training job failed
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnexpectedStatusException                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[28], line 1
----> 1 estimator.fit(train_input, job_name=job_name)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sagemaker/workflow/pipeline_context.py:311, in runnable_by_pipeline.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    307         return context
    309     return _StepArguments(retrieve_caller_name(self_instance), run_func, *args, **kwargs)
--> 311 return run_func(*args, **kwargs)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sagemaker/estimator.py:1322, in EstimatorBase.fit(self, inputs, wait, logs, job_name, experiment_config)
   1320 self.jobs.append(self.latest_training_job)
   1321 if wait:
-> 1322     self.latest_training_job.wait(logs=logs)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sagemaker/estimator.py:2605, in _TrainingJob.wait(self, logs)
   2603 # If logs are requested, call logs_for_jobs.
   2604 if logs != "None":
-> 2605     self.sagemaker_session.logs_for_job(self.job_name, wait=True, log_type=logs)
   2606 else:
   2607     self.sagemaker_session.wait_for_job(self.job_name)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sagemaker/session.py:4973, in Session.logs_for_job(self, job_name, wait, poll, log_type, timeout)
   4952 def logs_for_job(self, job_name, wait=False, poll=10, log_type="All", timeout=None):
   4953     """Display logs for a given training job, optionally tailing them until job is complete.
   4954 
   4955     If the output is a tty or a Jupyter cell, it will be color-coded
   (...)
   4971         exceptions.UnexpectedStatusException: If waiting and the training job fails.
   4972     """
-> 4973     _logs_for_job(self.boto_session, job_name, wait, poll, log_type, timeout)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sagemaker/session.py:6897, in _logs_for_job(boto_session, job_name, wait, poll, log_type, timeout)
   6894             last_profiler_rule_statuses = profiler_rule_statuses
   6896 if wait:
-> 6897     _check_job_status(job_name, description, "TrainingJobStatus")
   6898     if dot:
   6899         print()

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sagemaker/session.py:6950, in _check_job_status(job, desc, status_key_name)
   6944 if "CapacityError" in str(reason):
   6945     raise exceptions.CapacityError(
   6946         message=message,
   6947         allowed_statuses=["Completed", "Stopped"],
   6948         actual_status=status,
   6949     )
-> 6950 raise exceptions.UnexpectedStatusException(
   6951     message=message,
   6952     allowed_statuses=["Completed", "Stopped"],
   6953     actual_status=status,
   6954 )

UnexpectedStatusException: Error for Training job yolov5-t-3705a49b-162a-4bc4-9a4e-b7d271ebbcc7: Failed. Reason: AlgorithmError: ExecuteUserScriptError:
ExitCode 1
ErrorMessage "raise ValueError("SHA could not be resolved, git returned: %r" % (header_line.strip()))
 ValueError: SHA could not be resolved, git returned: b''"
Command "/opt/conda/bin/python3.8 train.py --batch-size 8 --data custom-model.yaml --device 0 --epochs 10 --project /opt/ml/model --weights yolov5s.pt --workers 8", exit code: 1
```

Comment: You are referring to an older example(>2 years) which might not be accurate, please try this out -m https://studiolab.sagemaker.aws/import/github/roboflow-ai/notebooks/blob/main/notebooks/train-yolov5-instance-segmentation-on-custom-data.ipynb

Comment: @RaghuRamesha thanks for the link, but that example isn't helpful.  First, it's on Google Colab, not AWS.  Second, it's running all the code on a local instance.  I don't have any problem cloning the YOLOv5 repo and running it locally on an EC2 instance or in a Sagemaker notebook.  The problem I'm having is training using the SageMaker interface and then deploying to a SageMaker endpoint.